# How many grams of coating is being yield per volume width?

Tags: geometry, arithmetic

The cylinder is 8.00 inches in diameter and 4.940 inches in width.
1.500 inches in width has a volume of 15.
3.440 inches in width has a volume of 12.
The total grams of coating yield from the both volumes is 80.
How many grams of coating is being yield per volume width?

Comment: I don't think I understand the phrasing of the question. What does "grams per volume width" mean? What are its units?

Comment: I should have removed the word width. I meant how many grams of coating will yield per volume? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it then just $80$ divided by the total volume?

Comment: I'd think grams of coating should be proportional to surface area, not volume.

Comment: I should have been clearer. Sorry about that. This is a coating cylinder with two engraving patterns on it. Pattern "A" has a coating transfer volume of 15. Pattern "B" has a coating transfer volume of 12. Both of them together transfer 80 grams of solution. How many grams of coating is being yield per volume? Perhaps this can help.

Comment: Let me know if I'm thinking properly: the surface area with the highest volume should be calculated as the overall volume. Then calculate the surface area of the smaller volume as the overall volume. From there I must deduct the difference between the larger and smaller, but only from the area of the smaller amount. That's where I'm lost.